# Can I access the target class instance in a Typescript method decorator?

Tags: typescript, decorator

I'm creating a WebSocket server in Typescript in which different application components should be able to register their own request handlers. There's a singleton `WebsocketHandler` that provides this behavior.

Without decorators, a class can register its request handlers like this:

```
class ListOfStuff {
  private list = [];

  constructor() {
    //Register listLengthRequest as a request handler
    WebsocketHandler.getInstance().registerRequestHandler('getListLength', () => this.listLengthRequest());
  }

  private listLengthRequest() : WebSocketResponse {
    return new WebSocketResponse(this.list.length);
  }
}

class WebsocketHandler {
  private constructor() {}

  private static instance = new WebsocketHandler();

  static getInstance() {
    return this.instance;
  }

  registerRequestHandler(requestName: string, handler: () => WebSocketResponse) {
    //Store this handler in a map for when a request is received later 
  }
}

class WebSocketResponse {
  constructor(content: any) {}
}
```

Which works fine. However, I'm trying to replace the registration calls in the constructor with method decorators. Ideally, ListOfStuff would then look like this:

```
class ListOfStuff {
  private list = [];

  @websocketRequest("getListLength")
  private listLengthRequest() : WebSocketResponse {
    return new WebSocketResponse(this.list.length);
  }
}
```

But, after creating a decorator factory for `@websocketRequest`, I can't figure out how to have `listLengthRequest()` execute in the correct context. I tried this factory function:

```
function websocketRequest(requestName: string) {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    WebsocketHandler.getInstance().registerRequestHandler(requestName, descriptor.value);
  }
}
```

Which makes `this` equal to the map the function is being held in (inside `WebsocketHandler`).

Then I tried passing in `target` as the handler's context with this factory function:

```
function websocketRequest(requestName: string) {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    WebsocketHandler.getInstance().registerRequestHandler(requestName, () => descriptor.value.call(target));
  }
}
```

But I then realised that `target` only refers to the prototype of `ListOfStuff` and not the actual class instance. So still not helpful.

Is there any way I can get the instance of `ListOfStuff` (so I can access `this.list`) in the decorator factory? Should I be structuring my decorator in some other way so that it's tied to the instance of the class rather than its prototype? Here's a Repl demonstrating the issue https://repl.it/@Chap/WonderfulLuckyDatalogs

This is the first time I've messed around with decorators, and I'm pretty new to Typescript too, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the goal is to call `listLengthRequest` of every `ListOfStuff` instance when something happens in `WebsocketHandler`?

Comment: Yep. There's logic inside `WebsocketHandler` that produces warnings if two methods register for the same `requestName`, so this is really only for classes that are created once. But there are also other `WebsocketHandler` callbacks I intend to expose using decorators that should fire on every instance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is not possible to access an instance in a Typescript method decorator. But it is possible to change the prototype and constructor using decorators. So the possible solution is to use two decorators: the first one that "marks" methods and the second one that changes the constructor adding the registration logic.

Below I'll try to illustrate the idea

```
const SubMethods = Symbol('SubMethods'); // just to be sure there won't be collisions

function WebsocketRequest(requestName: string) {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    target[SubMethods] = target[SubMethods] || new Map();
    // Here we just add some information that class decorator will use
    target[SubMethods].set(propertyKey, requestName);
  };
}

function WebSocketListener<T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }>(Base: T) {
  return class extends Base {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
      const subMethods = Base.prototype[SubMethods];
      if (subMethods) {
        subMethods.forEach((requestName: string, method: string) => {
          WebsocketHandler.getInstance()
            .registerRequestHandler(
              requestName,
              () => (this as any)[method]()
            );
        });
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
@WebsocketListener
class ListOfStuff {
  private list = [];

  @WebsocketRequest("getListLength")
  private listLengthRequest() : WebSocketResponse {
    return new WebSocketResponse(this.list.length);
  }
}
```

[Updated repl](https://repl.it/repls/WeeReasonableProprietarysoftware)

Comment: "It is not possible to access an instance in a Typescript method decorator.". You can access it in the function assigned to `descriptor.value`. See @AbhishekBorar's answer.

Comment: @spinkus there is a difference between "access an instance in a typescript method decorator" and "access an instance in a method". The problem stated in the question is about adding some metadata to the methods that then can be used in the constructor, and AbhishekBorar's answer answers to some other question.

Answer (score 22):

The following code snippet shows how we could access the target class instance from within a decorator for methods:

```
function log(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
  const originalValue = descriptor.value;

  descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
    // "this" here will refer to the class instance
    console.log(this.constructor.name);

    return originalValue.apply(this, args);
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
class Foo {

  @log
  bar() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting solution!

Comment: @Mahesh, in fact, it isn't empty. If it were arrow function then it would be empty bc of losing `this` context, but since `function` keyword is used and it is assigned to the prototype, `this` refers to the instance

Comment: I have no idea how it helps if it's cannot access anything expect `constructor` method in that instance object, or I don't get smthing

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. It would not help with registering the method to the WebsocketHandler.

Answer (score -1):

You can bind get the reference to the class instance by passing the this property inside the descriptor.value

Here is a example where you have a try catch decorator that allows you to call a config method with a context and perform some cleanup.

```js
export interface TryCatchConfigI<E = boolean> {
    label?: string
    onError?: (e: any, ...args: any) => E
    onErrorContext?: (e: any, ...args: any) => E
}

export type DecoratorT = (
    target: Record<string, any>,
    propertyKey: string,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
) => void

export function AsyncTryCatch<E>(config?: TryCatchConfigI<E>) {
    return function (
        target: any,
        propertyKey: string,
        descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
    ): void {
        const original = descriptor.value
        descriptor.value = async function (...args: any) {
            let result
            try {
                result = await original.apply(this, args)
                return result
            } catch (e: unknown) {
                config?.onErrorContext?.bind(this)(e, args)
                return config?.onError ? config.onError(e, args) : e
            }
        }
    }
}

class Test {
    private Cleanup() {
        console.log('cleanup')
    }

    @AsyncTryCatch({
        onErrorContext: () => {
            ;(this as unknown as Test).Cleanup()
        }
    })
    public OnError() {
        throw 'Some error happened'
    }
}

const instance = new Test()
instance.OnError()
```